# Any use of non-rectangular-shaped kernels in convolutional neural networks? Especially when analyzing game boards

Tags: references, conv-neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I have been reading a pile of papers on convolutional networks and reinforcement learning.

I remember seeing an important paper with a non-rectangular shape of the convolution layer (the green shape in this silly drawing). But now I cannot find it.

[image]

It might have been something similar to the AlphaGo paper or reinforced learning on a game board.

Can any one suggest or guess which paper it was?

Comment: Please explain CNN. After all Cable News Network also uses that acronym.

Comment: @Carl Convolutional Neural Networks !

Comment: I am not very familiar with ConvNets, but the whole idea is that they *learn* the appropriate filter(s) to use. So if it is appropriate to have 0's in the corners (or wherever), the ConvNet should be able to learn that. Any non-rectangular filter A is equivalent to a rectangular filter B over A's bounding box, combined with a mask (i.e. where B=0). Unless the filter A is very "convoluted", the savings in computation would be fairly negligible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to come up in earlier Herbrich papers on Go.

1. "Learning on Graphs in the Game of Go" - where he looks at the board as a different topology
2. And this slide in [a 2015 presentation he makes](http://mlss.tuebingen.mpg.de/2015/slides/herbrich/herbrich.pdf), mentioning 13 different "patterns"
   (which is somewhat different that the AlphaGo approach)

[image: Herbrich Go presentation slide]

**References**

- Graepel, T., Goutrie, M., Krüger, M., & Herbrich, R. (2001, August). "Learning on graphs in the game of Go." In *International Conference on Artificial Neural Networks* (pp. 347-352). Springer Berlin Heidelberg.
- Herbrich, R. (2015) "Machine Learning in Industry". Retrieved from http://mlss.tuebingen.mpg.de/2015/slides/herbrich/herbrich.pdf

Comment: Welcome to our site! I have added a full citation for the paper, could you add a link/reference to the presentation too?

Comment: @silverfish Thanks for citation.

Machine Learning in Industry.
mlss.tuebingen.mpg.de/2015/slides/herbrich/herbrich.pdf

Comment: Great, thanks. I have a feeling you may not have enough reputation yet to add more than a certain number of links (can't remember what the cut-off is) so I've edited that in too

Answer (score 4):

{1} compared square versus triangular 2D convolutions

[image]

As Geomatt22 mentions, in the example you gave the question, one could use a square filter and hope that the "actual" shape of the filter be  learnt during the training phase.

---

{1} Graham, Ben. "Sparse 3D convolutional neural networks." arXiv preprint arXiv:1505.02890 (2015). https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=10336237130292873407&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22 ; https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.02890

Comment: I would think rectangular vs. square would be more significant than rectangular vs. non-rectangular. In other words, if patterns are highly anisotropic, then skinny rectangles could be *much* more efficient than squares that are mostly "masked out". By comparison, the level of non-convexity needed to make a pattern's volume be much less than its bounding box seems unlikely to occur in practice (such a pattern would likely be a composite feature, vs. an appropriate template for low-level filters). Does such anisotropy occur in ConvNet applications? (In geology, this would be z small vs. x & y)